# angular directive function not found in scope

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I need to write a test for an angular directive but I am getting an error that Error: removeItem() method does not exist. I have been trying to fix it all day to the point of getting a headache, if anyone could point out what is wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

the directive

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('cartItem', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="cartItem"><div class="pull-left">' +
        '<p class="pull-left">{{ cartItem.brand_name }}' +
        '<a class="cartRemove" ng-click="removeItem(cartItem)">&nbsp;{{removeItemLabel}}</a>' +
        '</p></div><p class="cartItemPrice pull-right">{{ cartItem.priceUnformatted }} {{symbol}}</p></div>'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope) {
            scope.removeItem = function(entity){
                scope.removeItemFromCart(entity);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and my test

```
describe('', function(){
var element, scope;
beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {

    element = angular.element(
        '<div cart-item ' +
        'remove-item-from-cart="removeItemFromCart(item)"' +
        'attr-locale="\'EN\'" ' +
        'attr-remove-item-label="\'Remove item\'"' +
        'attr-formatted="true"' +
        'attr-cart-item=""></div>');

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should call remove on click', function(){
    spyOn(scope, 'removeItem');
    element.click();
    expect(scope.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

removeItem throws an error with the message Error: removeItem() method does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using isolated scope

```
    it('should call the remove function on click', function(){
        var isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
        spyOn(isolateScope, 'removeItemFromCart')
        isolateScope.removeItem();
        expect(isolateScope.removeItemFromCart).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your directive code the the code below:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('cartItem', function () {
    return {
       scope: true,
       template: '<div class="cartItem"><div class="pull-left">' +
          '<p class="pull-left">{{ cartItem.brand_name }}' +
          '<a class="cartRemove" ng-click="removeItem(cartItem)">&nbsp {{removeItemLabel}}</a>' +
    '</p></div><p class="cartItemPrice pull-right">{{ cartItem.priceUnformatted }} {{symbol}}</p></div>'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope) {
        scope.removeItem = function(entity){
            scope.removeItemFromCart(entity);
        };
      }
  };
});
```

This will allow your directive to inherit the scope from the current controller. I think that's what you need in this case. This is a good article on scopes and custom directives: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx